# Can $\Bbb Z[\frac16]/{\sim}$ inherit the topology from the 2-adic integers $\Bbb Z_2$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, p-adic-number-theory

> Can $\Bbb Z[\frac16]/{\sim}$ inherit the topology from the 2-adic integers $\Bbb Z_2$, and is it compact?

Where $\sim$ says $x\sim y\iff 2^nx=2^{-n}y$

---

It seems obvious $\Bbb Z[\frac16]$ doesn't naturally do so, since it contains numbers $x$ satisfying $\lvert x\rvert_2>1$, which aren't in $\Bbb Z_2$

But every class defined by $\Bbb Z[\frac16]/{\sim}$ is either $\{0\}$ or a pair having a unique element in $\Bbb Z[\frac16]>0$ so this claim seems equivalent to asking whether $\Bbb Z[\frac16]\geq0$ can inherit the topology, which it seems to trivially do.

As for whether it's compact, this seems to hang on whether there exists a finite subcover of $\Bbb Z[\frac16]/{\sim}$, and I'm a bit lost in that regard.

Comment: I guess it can still inherit the topology from $\mathbb{Q}_2$.

Comment: @daruma I think all $\Bbb Z[\frac16]$ can do that, irrespective of the equivalence relation - although I would still not understand whether it's compact.

Comment: Your equivalence relation is unclear to me; as written all it says that there is some $n$ with $y=4^nx$, and I don't _think_ that's what you mean. If you mean that $x$ and $y$ differ by a power of two then that would be better written as just $x\equiv y\Longleftrightarrow\exists n (x=2^ny)$; if you mean something more symmetric then you should be clearer about it. And similar to your other questions about equivalence relations, these equivalence relations 'respect' the multiplication operation, but not addition, so it's not entirely clear what structures your symbols represent.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I think the relation says e.g. $12\sim\frac34$ but not $12\sim48$ whereas I think you've interpreted it as $2^{n-2}$.  But yes, I see your point re addition, it would degenerate unless defined only on either $\lvert x\rvert_2\geq1$ or $\lvert x\rvert_2\leq1$

Comment: $12\sim 48$ would arise by taking $x=12, y=48, n=1$; $2^112=2^{-1}48$. It sounds like you mean specifically to take $\{2^n\cdot r\}$, for $r$ odd, and say that $2^{-n}\cdot r\sim2^n\cdot r$, but that definitely doesn't play well with addition at all and it seems highly unnatural to me here.